# Array Modifier with Offset Object Issue

Tags: modifiers

I'm going through Roland Hess' Blender Foundations book and I am having issues with the array modifier (using offset object).

I am trying to make feet for a table, my issue is that rotating the offset object (an empty named "empty" in the file) does nothing.

All I can see is the single object with the array copied right in the same position.

The [blend is here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h6ty9mmwmuwwvpw/Flower%20007.blend), help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Seems to be working fine here, how are you rotatinf this? You just have to select the empty alone and rotate it in Z axis. Just make sure the *Manipulate Center Points* only option isn't checked in the 3D View Header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable "Manipulate Center Points" to be able to rotate the object the way that you are thinking:

[image]

Funniest thing is, I went through that same book years ago and had the same problem while making that table :-)

Comment: Hah!  Thanks for the help on this one.  I've noticed that Hess likes to handwave details at the most inconvenient times.

Comment: Yeah, he doesn't have time to go over every setting, so he assumes they are set to defaults. Please accept my answer since it answered your question.